# Which is mathematically more valuable for my fighter, Archery or Dueling?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, fighter

I have a fighter with really high rolls, 18 strength, 17 dexterity, 17 constitution. I'll eventually be getting 18 in all three of those, I'm currently level 4. I have a warhammer and a heavy crossbow. I have the crossbow expert feat (ignore loading, melee disadvantage). I intend on fighting with a warhammer and shield in melee and my heavy crossbow at range.

Archery will be giving me a +2 on ranged attack rolls, while dueling is a +2 on melee damage rolls. Which of those is more valuable?

Comment: How exactly do you define "valuable?" Are you looking for the fighting style that's optimized for damage with no other consideration?

Comment: Given it's a choice between damage and accuracy, I don't see how either of them would provide any utility.

Comment: Dueling lets you use a shield, which gives you  +2 AC. Also, there are some feats that synergize more with one fighting style than the other. In that respect, it's important to know if you care only about damage, or about overall versitility

Comment: Overall versatility is good. I plan on using both weapons, I just had a gut feeling that one of those wouldn't scale very well. I didn't think the 2 damage would help much as numbers got higher, but thinking about it, you get that 2 damage on every single attack you use, so it might be pretty good. Especially since I'm Battlemaster with Riposte so I'll be getting more attacks out.

Comment: A few questions, and I can work up an interesting (to me) spreadsheet: (a) what armor are you wearing, and what do you intend to wear through your levels? (b) Which levels do you care about? (*I.e.* Do you expect this character will top out at 12 or 18?) (c) What are you going to do with your ASIs after you've maxed your primary attack stat? (Only need to know if it's something that somehow affects combat.)

Comment: I'm currently wearing chainmail, and the GM is a stingy bastard, so I'll probably be wearing that for a long time. I don't think this character will be very long lived. I'll be picking up a few more feats, then topping up stats.

Comment: Wait, wha!? You're going to take feats before ASI? Which feats? This is pretty important. And by "not very long-lived do you mean L6 or L12?